# JAX-RS - Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type

Tags: jax-rs

I am trying to work out a sample of JAX-RS in JBoss 7.2 Rest Easy. I am getting a Error message as below.

> SEVERE [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:80-2) Failed executing GET /test/resources/1:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not
>   find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: vsample.Image of
>   media type: image/jpeg    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:216)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeJaxrsResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:602)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:528)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

And my code is,

```
 import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
     import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
     import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


     @ApplicationPath("/rest")
   public class Etag extends Application {
    }
```

And,

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl;
import javax.ws.rs.core.EntityTag;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;


@Path( "/test" )
public class EtagImpl {

   @GET
   @Produces("image/jpeg")

   @Path("resources/{id}")
      public Response getImage(@PathParam("id") String id, @Context Request request) {

       ImageDAOImpl imageDAO = new ImageDAOImpl();

        Image image = imageDAO.getImage(id);
       CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
       cc.setMaxAge(172800); // 2 days
       Response.ResponseBuilder rb = null;
       String lastModified = image.getDateModified().toString();
     //  EntityTag etag = new EntityTag(imageDAO.getImage(id).hashCode()+"");
       EntityTag etag = new EntityTag(lastModified.hashCode()+"");
       System.out.println("Writing Response:" + etag);
       rb = request.evaluatePreconditions(etag);
       if (rb != null) 
       {
           return rb.cacheControl(cc).tag(etag).build();
       }

       //If rb is null then either it is first time request; or resource is modified
       //Get the updated representation and return with Etag attached to it
               rb = Response.ok(imageDAO.getImage(id)).cacheControl(cc).tag(etag);
               return rb.build();
    }
```

As I am new to RestEasy, it will be helpful to get ideas to proceed in right direction

Thanks and Regards,
Ram.

Answer (score 11):

This simply means that RestEasy does not know how to "convert" your Image object to the mediatype ("image/jpeg") you specified in the @Produces annotation.

By default there's only a limited list of supported types that resteasy can automatically marshal and unmarshal :

- java.lang.String
- byte[]
- java.io.InputStream
- java.io.Reader
- java.io.File
- javax.activation.DataSource
- javax.xml.transform.Source
- javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
- JAXB classes,
- javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap

The easiest way to do it would be to have the Response filled with the byte array representation of your image.

```
Response.ok(imageDAO.getImage(id).getBytes()).cacheControl(cc).tag(etag);
```

An other option would be to write you own MessageBodyWriter that will take care of this conversion.
Have a look at the the resteasy documentation for more details http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.5.Final/userguide/html/Content_Marshalling_Providers.html

Comment: This is true! I tried to wrap Integer into the Response, but failed for the whole day, thank you! Really helpful